# In material-react-table, how do I change the styling for different density values?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, material-react-table

I just want to change the styling for the different density modes like "compact" and "comfortable" in the `<MaterialReactTable />` table component. This is using the material-react-table npm library by Material UI.

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { useMemo } from 'react';
import { MaterialReactTable } from 'material-react-table';
import { data } from './makeData';

const Example = () => {
  const columns = useMemo(
    //column definitions...
    [],
  );

  return (
    <MaterialReactTable
      columns={columns}
      data={data}
      enableDensityToggle={false}
      initialState={{ density: 'compact' }}
    />
  );
};

export default Example;
```

You can use something like this, also detail are available in below link<

https://www.material-react-table.com/docs/guides/density-toggle

Comment: How do I add CSS though for a specific density? Like say if I wanted to set different padding values for "compact" and "comfortable"

Comment: Try using this.  
`const specialCSS = "<style>.MuiTableCell-root.MuiTableCell-body.MuiTableCell-alignLeft { padding: 0 !important } .MuiTableCell-root.MuiTableCell-body.MuiTableCell-paddingNone .MuiIconButton-root { padding: 0 !important }</style>"`  
`<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: specialCSS}}></div>`    
Link: https://github.com/mbrn/material-table/issues/290

   
options={{
                cellStyle: { padding: '0.3em'},
                headerStyle: { padding: '0.3em'},
              }}

Answer (score 0):

You can use State Options and Customize (Style) Components Guide

```
const [density, setDensity] = useState<MRT_DensityState>('compact');

//MaterialReactTable
state={{ isLoading, sorting, density }}
onDensityChange={setDensity}

muiTableBodyCellProps={({cell}) => ({
     sx: {padding: (density === 'compact' ? '10px': '20px')}
})}
```